# AutoMapper map using linked maps / Transitive mapping / Chain maps

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

In C# dotnet, using AutoMapper how can I create a map that uses chained mappings / map using other maps to intermediary types?

In the example a map from type A to type B exists, and also from B to C.
So a map from A to C could be created using the above two: combining them or using the first to map to an object of type B and then the second for the final map, through the path: A -> B -> C.

In more complex scenarios there could be more than a single path so one needs to be specified, but how?

```
public class A
{
    public string TestA { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string TestB { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string TestC { get; set; }
}

this.CreateMap<A, B>()
.ForMember(dst => dst.TestB, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.TestA));
this.CreateMap<B, C>()
.ForMember(dst => dst.TestC, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.TestB));

this.CreateMap<A, C>();// A -> B -> C
// something like .UsingMap<A, B>().ThenUsingMap<B, C>()
```

How can we express this?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Comment: I know I can use a custom converter or a conversion function, but the point is to write a minimal amount of code, and possibly retain the ability to map expression as well.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found this question trying to do the same. If I'm not wrong, you have A->B and B->C, and you want A->C.

To do this, what I did was to create this two maps and then I used `ConvertUsing` like this:

```
CreateMap<A, B>();

CreateMap<B, C>();

CreateMap<A, C>()
  .ConvertUsing((entity, c, context) =>
    {
      var intermediate = context.Mapper.Map<B>(entity);
      return context.Mapper.Map<C>(intermediate);
    });
```

It just worked for me. I don't know if what you are looking for is more complex or has a different needs/end but for me it was a pretty simple map but the first one (A->B) had legacy logic I didn't want to repeat in B->C so I did this to reuse the previous mapping. Let me know what you think and if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I ended up with a similar solution, it works for object mapping but not for expressions, as stated. I searched the documentation twice, but didn't find anything useful for the matter. Although it should be pretty straightforward (in this case) to derive a mapping i.e. if property TestA maps to TestB (A -> B) and TestB to TestC (B -> C) then TestA should map to TestC (A -> C) but people cannot implement this kind of behavior themselves because at configuration time maps are not accessible. I think it's a tradeoff, if you want to map expressions, you'll need to write some duplicate code.

Comment: I was able to get this to work when like this: `var mapped = _mapper.Map<DestinationType>(source)`, but it didn't seem to work for this scenario: `_mapper.Map(source, destination)`. The destination object ended up unchanged. For my scenario, where I was modifying a context object, this means I had to go all the way through `var typeBIntermediate = Map<B>(typeAChangeItem)` and then `_mapper.Map(typeBIntermediate, typeCItemToUpdate)`. If anyone knows why I'd be very interested.